# Vectorial clothes / hair cuts that adapt on any character size, how is it done?

Tags: graphics, vector, graphics-design

Rimworld characters are simple but very nice to watch.
They have different sizes, hair cuts, clothes...
And everything seems to adapt to everyone. How does that work technically ?

For example, any vest will adapt to every characters sizes.
I highly doubt that the artists designed every vests for every body shape as it would be a tremendous amount of work.

I think they use vectors, and somehow get it to work. But how ?

See Veli & Baldwin or Tau & Kish below:

[image: A rimworld screenshot]

Or Flebe and maria below, they both wear a lightleather parka.

[image: Another one]

Comment: Looks like raster to me, probably simple scaling is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I highly doubt that the artists designed every vests for every body shape as it would be a tremendous amount of work

I am pretty sure that this is exactly what they did. There aren't actually that many body shapes in the game. It's not much work because the torsos of the characters in Rimworld have no animation at all and the graphic style is very simplistic. You just need to create three frames per item and body shape: front, back and side (left and right can be mirrored).

Different materials with the same clothes cut and different skin tones for the same body can be created by recoloring the sprites at runtime.

The hair is another recolored sprite which is drawn on top of the character at runtime.